# Why does exponentiation (e.g., 10^6) take 4 times longer than calculator notation (e.g., 1e6) in R?

Tags: r, performance, time, exponentiation, coding-efficiency

Using the scientific notation `10^6` in an R code (as I customarily do) results in a significantly longer computing time than using the calculator representation `1e6`:

```
> system.time(for (t in 1:1e7) x=10^6) 
  utilisateur     système      écoulé 
        4.792       0.000       4.281 
> system.time(for (t in 1:1e7) x=1e6) 
 utilisateur     système      écoulé 
       0.804       0.000       1.051
> system.time(for (t in 1:1e7) x=exp(6*log(10)))
 utilisateur     système      écoulé 
       6.301       0.000       5.702
```

Why is it the case that R recomputes `10^6` in about the same times as it computes `exp{6*log(10)}`? I understand the fact that R executes a function when computing `10^6`, but why was it coded this way?

Comment: I'd guess that one is a numeric literal that only needs to be translated while the other is an expression that first needs to be evaluated.

Comment: Why do you think that R calculates `10^6` via `exp(6*log(10))`?

Comment: @cryo111: I do not know how R computes `10^6`but it takes as long as using `exp(6*log(10))`. I will rephrase this sentence, thank you.

Comment: It's not a matter of "being coded in a particular way" as you say but that you are explicitly telling R to compute 10 to the power of 6... For instance, would you rather assign `double a=1e6;` or `double a=pow(10,6);` in C++?

Comment: @cryo111: I understand the reason but bemoan the loss in efficiency when using a power notation. This is not the end of the world, but I have to be careful about this in my future codes.

Comment: @Xi'an A good question BTW. Also, you got two nice answers with some interesting additional insights by MrFlick and Josh. +1 all

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's because `1e6` is a [constant](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Constants), and is recognized as such by the parser, whereas `10^6` is parsed as a function call which has to be further evaluated (by a call to the function `^()`). Since the former avoids the expensive overhead of a function call, evaluating it is a lot faster!

```
class(substitute(1e6))
# [1] "numeric"
class(substitute(10^6))
# [1] "call"
```

To better see that it's a call, you can dissect it like this:

```
as.list(substitute(10^6))
# [[1]]
# `^`
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 10
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 6
```

A few other interesting cases:

```
## negative numbers are actually parsed as function calls
class(substitute(-1))
[1] "call"

## when you want an integer, 'L' notation lets you avoid a function call 
class(substitute(1000000L))
# [1] "integer"
class(substitute(as.integer(1000000)))
# [1] "call"
```

Comment: Very interesting additional cases! But puzzling. I had never heard of using the L before (but it does not seem to save time when allocating a negative number)

Comment: @Xi'an Yeah, R's use of a trailing `L` to indicate integers is distinct from its treatment of `-` as a function call. As far as I know, there's simply no way to supply a negative constant without executing a function call --- no `"1N"` or the like.

Answer (score 8):

In the case of `1e6` you are specifying a literal numeric value. There is no calculation happening there.

When you request `10^6`, R does the work of raising 10 to the 6th power. The `^` is a numeric operator. It doesn't do anything special for base 10. It doesn't know the different between `10^6` and `12^14`. It must do the calculation to find the answer.

Comment: Thanks. It is sad that 10 is not given special status, though!

Comment: Giving 10 special status would complicate the parser.  I have obviously done no tests, but chances are this will slow things down more than the occasional power calculation.